# What should I do with a question that has a workaround, but no direct answer?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have an open question that is unsolved, but I have come up with an alternate approach that avoids the original problem. I posted my workaround as an edit to my question, because I think it might be helpful to someone else facing the same problem.

I didn't post it as an answer because it doesn't really address the original question. I also don't feel like my workaround is the best way to avoid the problem, and would prefer to find a solution to the original question.

My question now, is whether that was the correct approach. Should I have posted the alternate approach as an answer? Or just added a comment?

The question I'm referencing:
[Add text label with semi transparent background to an image using Magick.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75227047/add-text-label-with-semi-transparent-background-to-an-image-using-magick-net)

Comment: Essentially your three options were: edit the answer into the question, post the answer, post a comment. There is a fourth option which is to not do anything of course. And of all those options, you picked editing the answer into the question. Methinks you overthink things a little :)

Comment: "Methinks you overthink things a little :)" -- A common trait in software development, isn't it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A workaround is "a direct answer". In particular, it is a *solution to the problem* that was asked about. It may not work for everyone, and it may not be ideal, but it is a valid solution. Solutions never belong in the question; they should always get posted as answers.

Furthermore, the posting of one answer does not foreclose the possibility of getting additional (hopefully better) answers in the future. That you think the solution is less than ideal should never deter you or anyone else from posting it, *especially* in the absence of a better solution. The whole design of Q&A on Stack Overflow is that the best solutions rise to the top.

This remains true even when an answer has been "accepted" by the asker of the question. That a question is shown as "answered" by the system because it has an accepted answer (one with a green checkmark by it) doesn't mean that no more answers (especially better ones) are welcome. It just means that the asker of the question indicated the answer that worked the best for them *at that moment*. But, certainly, as the asker of the question, if you're unhappy with the solution provided by an answer (whether it's yours or someone else's), you should not feel obligated to accept it. That serves as an even clearer sign that the question hasn't yet received a *good* (dare I say…*acceptable*) answer.

(Solutions don't belong in comments, either. Comments are for suggesting improvements to the post, asking for clarification, and possibly providing supporting information that cannot stand on its own because it doesn't present a solution to the problem, like a link to the associated documentation.)

Answer (score 5):

Take a step back. What actually is the question?

When you initially asked how to "Add text label with semi transparent background to an image using Magick.NET", were you trying to get a specific visual effect? Or was it specifically about doing things in a specific way, in order to understand the API?

Let's reread:

> I wound up creating the transparent overlay using my original .Net Drawing code, and passing that as a memory stream to Imagemagick.Net to handle the merge. It's not really an answer to my original question

**Exactly why isn't it**, as asked? Upon reflection, did you ask the question you intended to ask? Does the workaround answer the question *that you would ask now, knowing what you do*? It sounds to me like you did succeed in adding a text label to the image, that the label does have a semi-transparent background, and that Magick.NET is used. You *draw* the elements there, you just *merge* them elsewhere.

If it's good enough, then post it as an answer (and consider clarifying the question such that it's obvious that the answer is acceptable). If you still, separately, want to know how to do the merging in Magick.NET, that sounds to me like the basis for a **new question**.

If it isn't good enough, then the question should explain why. **Briefly** acknowledge the workaround ("I know I can get the visual effect I want by drawing the elements and then handing them off to another tool for composition") without showing code for it (it doesn't help understand the question, and isn't part of what you're asking about), and **explicitly** state why that isn't good enough (", but...").

But definitely don't put anything in the question that comes across like an answer to the question. This is a question and answer site, not a quanswer and blank space site.